# Issues with "has_one" in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to do something extremely simple but can't find a solution in [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

I have two tables, `words` and `flavors`. There's a dictionary's worth of words, and only about 10 flavors. I want each word to have a flavor.

I've tried many combinations of `flavor_id` and `word_id` in the migrations, and `has_one` and `belongs_to` in the models, but always run into problems. Giving the `has_one` to the `word` isn't right because then each flavor could only be associated to one `word`. Flipping the `has_one` doesn't help because it prevents me from doing things like `word.flavor = Flavor.some_flavor`.

Is there a method for handling such scenarios?

**Update**: I had to drop both tables and recreate them, and David Underwood's solution worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some class definitions that will work:

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :flavor
end

class Flavor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :words
end
```

In your schema, you want the `words` table to have a `flavor_id` column. You don't need a foreign key on the `flavors` table.

The key is that each word is associated with a single flavor, and a single flavor can be associated with many words.

You can now call `word.flavor` to get the flavor of a word as well as `flavor.words` to get an array of words with that flavor.

Comment: I had tried that already, but I get this:`
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: flavors.word_id: SELECT  "flavors".* FROM "flavors"  WHERE "flavors"."word_id" = ?  ORDER BY "flavors"."id" ASC LIMIT 1` 
upon executing `Word.first.flavor = Flavor.first`.